# Unable to execute SELECT statement when using cursor obj from Ibm_db_dbi

Tags: python, db2

I've connected successfully to a db using ibm_db, but I'm always getting the same error when trying to execute a statement with execute method. This is my code:

```
import ibm_db,ibm_db_dbi
conn=ibm_db.pconnect("DATABASE=mydb;HOSTNAME=Hostname;PORT=xxxx;AUTHENTICATION=SERVER;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=usr;PWD=pwd;", "", "")
con=ibm_db_dbi.Connection(conn) 
sql="SELECT * FROM xxxxx.xxxxx"
curs=con.cursor()   
curs.execute(sql)
```

The error I get is:

> ProgrammingError: ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][AS] SQL0551N          The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.  Authorization ID: "".  Operation: "". Object: "NULLID.SYSSH200".  SQLSTATE=42501 SQLCODE=-551

The same SQL statement works fine if I use it the IBM i Access SQL console, so I think I should be allowed to perform the operation.

Answer (score 0):

The Python ib_db module uses the CLI packages (because python ibm_db is written in C and uses the CLI API to access to Db2). But the IBM i access driver does not not use these packages (it's written mostly in java). That is the reason you see a **difference** in behaviour between the two drivers.

To correct the issue, you will need to ask your i admin person to perform a bind action using files on your workstation.  This can be done from your workstation but needs the authid of an IBM i admin (or anytone with suitable authorization to perform a bind action on the database on the ibm i, e.g. anyone with DBADM rights ).

The main file is ...`\site-packages\clidriver\bin\db2cli.lst`  (where site-packages is your python packages location, visible in `pip show ibm_db` output).

To perform the bind action, it is necessary to first create and configure the `db2dsdriver.cfg` file, which defines the connection details and parameters of any target database and also defines the DSN (data source names) corresponding to the remote databases.  Refer to the documentation (google for examples).

Then you can use the `db2cli` command to perform the bind action using a command line similar to:

`db2cli bind @db2cli.lst -dsn XXX -user YYY -passwd ZZZ -options "grant public"`

where XXX corresponpds to the DSN you created/configured in `db2driver.cfg`, YYY is an authid on IBM-i that has bind authorization (or DBADM rights), and ZZZ is the password for that authod.   Note that you should **either** fully qualify the pathname for `db2cli.lst` in that command line (its full path), or alternatively use `cd` to change into its directory before running the command.   The bind action takes a few seconds, and the result is effective immediately, and the CLI packages will then be executable by your regular authid.

**Note 1**: if the i admin has access to a full db2 CLP (command line processor) on a separate machine that is **already configured** to access the same IBM i database, then the same bind action can be done on that environment **as long as** the exact same bindfiles that are on your workstation (exact same versions) are used , for example `db2 connect to XXX user YYY using ZZZ`  followed by `db2 bind @db2cli.lst blocking all grant public`  and `db2 connect reset`.

**Note 2**: The i admin can also run individual grant statements (example, `grant execute on NULLID.SYSSH200 to public` directly on the i database using whatever preferred interface is normally used. However, it is likely that other additional packages will need to be granted similarly, and that is the reason for using all of the packages that are specified inside the `db2cli.lst` file. Other packages can get used depending on which aspects of ibm_db you invoke now or later).